# csv to xml command line and condition

Tags: xml, csv, awk

I am trying to convert a csv to a xml file using awk.  To better understand i give a exemple of my csv file:

```
name;num_tel;num_fixe;id_client;num_comd    
gwenael;0998452223;1038431234;50C;12345   
marcel;0966442312;1038453211;31C;654321     
judith;0954674487;1045227937;23D;78965
paul;0998452223;1038431234;35X;19945
toto;0966442312;1038453211;31Z;994991  
marie;0954674487;1045227937;23C;78944
jacque;0998452223;1038431234;77C;18845
trucmuche;0966442312;1038453211;31Z;666321  
tata;0954674487;1045227937;23D;77965
```

My objective is to take the third letter of id_client (C,D,X,Z), and if for example:
the letter is C in the xml i will have the tag name, num_comd and tel_fixe only .
If the letter is D i will have the tag name, id_client, num_fixe

I succeed in taking the letter with awk script pipe with command cut and put it in a variable 
now i'am here :

```
 if(var==C) 
  {}
Else if (var==D)
{}
```

Can you help me please to resolve problem about how input the right xml tag?
I am pretty new with command line.

Sorry for the writing mistakes. I am french.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an executable awk script example, where I created several helper functions to re-use code:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS=";"
    documentEnclosingTag = "rows"
    c_flds["name"]; c_flds["num_comd"]; c_flds["num_tel"]
    d_flds["name"]; d_flds["id_client"]; d_flds["num_fixe"]
    x_flds["name"]
    z_flds["name"]

    print "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
    printf "<%s>\n", documentEnclosingTag
}

FNR==1 { gsub(" ", ""); for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) cols[$i]=i; next }

$(cols["id_client"]) ~ /C$/ { print createObject( "C", c_flds ) }
$(cols["id_client"]) ~ /D$/ { print createObject( "D", d_flds ) }
$(cols["id_client"]) ~ /X$/ { print createObject( "X", x_flds ) }
$(cols["id_client"]) ~ /Z$/ { print createObject( "Z", z_flds ) }

END { printf "</%s>\n", documentEnclosingTag }

#----------- functions -----------

function createObject( enclosingTag, flds,          key, s) {
    for(key in flds) {
        s = s "\t" wrapData( key, $(cols[key]) ) "\n"
    }
    return( wrapData( enclosingTag, "\n" s ) )
}

function wrapData( enclosingTag, data ) {
    return( sprintf( "<%s>%s</%s>", enclosingTag, data, enclosingTag ) )
}
```

You could put this in a file (`script.awk`), make it executable and then run it like

```
./script.awk data > data.xml
```

where `data` is the name I gave your data file, and `data.xml` is where the data will end up.

The output is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rows>
<C>
        <num_tel>0998452223</num_tel>
        <name>gwenael</name>
        <num_comd>12345   </num_comd>
</C>
<C>
        <num_tel>0966442312</num_tel>
        <name>marcel</name>
        <num_comd>654321     </num_comd>
</C>
<D>
        <id_client>23D</id_client>
        <num_fixe>1045227937</num_fixe>
        <name>judith</name>
</D>
<X>
        <name>paul</name>
</X>
<Z>
        <name>toto</name>
</Z>
<C>
        <num_tel>0954674487</num_tel>
        <name>marie</name>
        <num_comd>78944</num_comd>
</C>
<C>
        <num_tel>0998452223</num_tel>
        <name>jacque</name>
        <num_comd>18845</num_comd>
</C>
<Z>
        <name>trucmuche</name>
</Z>
<D>
        <id_client>23D</id_client>
        <num_fixe>1045227937</num_fixe>
        <name>tata</name>
</D>
</rows>
```

I'm sure I'm not using the correct terminology for the various parts of the XML file, but this output can be loaded by a browser as "valid"(parseable) XML.  You'd probably want to look into a DTD if this file should be give to anyone else.

Here's the general breakdown:

- In the `BEGIN` block, set the field separator to `;`, initialize variables like the desired output field for each "Object" and `documentEnclosingTag`, then print a generic XML header along with the `documentEnclosingTag`
- In the `FNR==1` block, take the first row of the data as the headers and put them into the `cols` array so flds can be referenced by their header names later on.  Clean the data with a `gsub` call to trim the column names
- For each `$(cols["id_client"])` block, print an appropriate "Object", by specifying an enclosingTag value and the matching desired flds array.
- In the `END`, print the closing `documentEnclosingTag`

As for the functions:

- `wrapData` creates a string with enclosing tags around the data.
- `createObject` uses `wrapData` to create the elements and the enclosing tags for the "Object" itself, where I added a little output formatting using awk's standard string concatenation.  The `flds` array indicates the desired output fields.  The `key` and `s` are local variables for the function.  Each `fld`, data and tag are concatenated to `s` and then finally `s` is wrapped by the `enclosingTag` and returned as a string.

Comment: thank 's a lot for your tutorial extremly interessing me, i'am trying to adapted to my code and certainely i'll come back for over question.

Comment: I'am back for a question about how do you check the letter, take for exemple the C of id_client. If for exemple instead of 50C we have 50C0145. how can i do it ?  thank you

Comment: Breaking down `$(cols["id_client"]) ~ /C$/` is like saying "match the record where the fourth fld's value is matched by the regular expression where `C` is at the end of the field".  Droping the `$` from `/C$/` will do what you want:  `$(cols["id_client"]) ~ /C/`.  Examining each part:  `$(cols["id_client"])` => `$(4)` => `$4`, `~` => "matched by", `/C$/` => the regular expression of `C` at the end of the field that preceeds the `~`.

Comment: hello,  i had a over question this way, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29456382/csv-to-xml-with-various-tag-name. Can you help me again please ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of reading a file named `in` with the example data you gave.

```
awk -F\; '$4~/C/ {print "<name>"$1"</name>"} $4~/D/{print "<name>"$1"</name><id_client>"$4"</id_client>"}' < in
```

You should be able to fill in the extra xml elements you need to expand on this example.

The output of this command is:

`<name>gwenael</name>
<name>marcel</name>
<name>judith</name><id_client>23D</id_client>
<name>marie</name>
<name>jacque</name>
<name>tata</name><id_client>23D</id_client>`