# Csv to xml with various tag name

Tags: xml, csv

I have this  csv file

```
name;num_tel;num_fixe;id_client;num_comd;email;city;date_liv
gwenael;0998452223;1038431234;50C;12345;gwa@yahoo.fr;London;08/07/2015
marcel;0966442312;1038453211;31C;654321;marcel@yahoo.fr;Pairs;08/06/2015
judith;0954674487;1045227937;23D;78965;judith@yahoo.fr;Toulouse;11/05/2015
paul;0998452223;1038431234;35X;19945;paul@yahoo.fr;Bordeaux;01/04/2015
toto;0966442312;1038453211;31Z;994991;toto@yahoo.frNice;02/12/2015 
marie;0954674487;1045227937;23C;78944;marie@yahoo.fr;Lille;04/08/2015
jacque;0998452223;1038431234;77C;18845;jacque@yahoo.fr;Bruges;09/05/2015
trucmuche;0966442312;1038453211;31Z;666321;trucmuche@yahoo.fr;Berlin;10/04/2015 
tata;0954674487;1045227937;23D;77965;tata@yahoo.fr;New-york;08/07/2015
```

In my case, those tag name are in default value, users  have the possibility to had
 more tag name for exemple i added  city, date_liv. So they add it and generate the csv.
 they appear after the last default tag name (email).
 i would like to know if it is possible to make a loop to check into the csv  and add them to the xml ?
 I think the loop will looks like for(i=7; i<=NF;i++) {} ?   but how to make it ?
 Here is what i did can you help me to well formed it please i have so much mistake

```
BEGIN {

FS=";"
documentEnclosingTag = "rows"
c_flds["id_client"];c_flds["name"];c_flds["num_cmd"];c_flds["num_tel"];d_flds["email"]
d_flds["id_client"];d_flds["name"];d_flds["num_fixe"];d_flds["num_tel"];

print "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
printf "<%s>\n", documentEnclosingTag
}

FNR==1 { gsub(" ", ""); for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) cols[$i]=i; next }

var = $(cols["ID_client_proxy"]) 
if ( var ~ /C/ )
{ print createObject( "C", c_flds ) }
else { print createObject( "D", d_flds ) }

END { printf "</%s>\n", documentEnclosingTag }

#----------- functions -----------

function createObject( enclosingTag, flds,key, s) {
    for(key in flds) {
        s = s "\t" wrapData( key, $(cols[key]) ) "\n"
    }
    return( wrapData( enclosingTag, "\n" s ) )
}

function wrapData( enclosingTag, data ) {
    return( sprintf( "<%s>%s</%s>", enclosingTag, data, enclosingTag ) )
}
```

Comment: You should get in the habit of testing the script you post as well showing desired outputs.  In this case, I'm familiar with the other question.  You also probably want to shorten the test data to one header, one "C" and one "D".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rewrite of the script to allow for non-default flds to be appended to the known fields for each "Object" type ( "C" and "D" ).  The most noteable differences are in the `BEGIN` block and what happens when the "header" row is parsed:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {

    FS=";"
    documentEnclosingTag = "rows"

      # name the default flds with "_", "C" and "D" represent "Objects"
    dflt_flds["id_client"] = "_CD"
    dflt_flds["name"]      = "_CD"
    dflt_flds["num_comd"]  = "_C"
    dflt_flds["num_tel"]   = "_CD"
    dflt_flds["email"]     = "_C"
    dflt_flds["num_fixe"]  = "D"

    print "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
    printf "<%s>\n", documentEnclosingTag
}

FNR==1 {
    gsub(" ", "")
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        cols[$i]=i
        dflt = dflt_flds[$i]
        if( dflt ~ /C/ || dflt == "" ) c_flds[$i]
        if( dflt ~ /D/ || dflt == "" ) d_flds[$i]
    }
    next
}

  # set var for every record read
{ var = $(cols["id_client"]) }

  # use var to determine which kind of record to print
var ~ /C/ { print createObject( "C", c_flds ) }
var ~ /D/ { print createObject( "D", d_flds ) }

END { printf "</%s>\n", documentEnclosingTag }

#----------- functions -----------

function createObject( enclosingTag, flds,             key, s) {
    for(key in flds) {
        s = s "\t" wrapData( key, $(cols[key]) ) "\n"
    }
    return( wrapData( enclosingTag, "\n" s ) )
}

function wrapData( enclosingTag, data ) {
    return( sprintf( "<%s>%s</%s>", enclosingTag, data, enclosingTag ) )
}
```

- `BEGIN` - Instead of naming each default column, we need a kind of "bitmask" for defaults and each "Object" type.  So create that with a `dflt_flds` array which names each of possible data types each known column is associated with.  `_` is being reserved to mean a default or otherwise known field.  If `_` is a valid "id_client" identifier you'll want to change that to another single char.  The other field's defaults are denoted by their "C" or "D" value in that same string.  Notice that `c_flds` and `d_flds` are constructed later - when the header is parsed.
- `FNR==1` - when the header field is parsed to create `cols`, check the value at `dflt_flds[$i]`.  Next, the default flds for each "Object" are created.  If `dlft` matches "C" or an empty string then it's considered a `c_flds` required field and added to that array.  `d_flds` is similarly constructed.
- After that, the `id_client` field is consulted to determine how to print each "C" and "D" type "Object" similarly to how it was originally done(1), though the "var" variable was preserved and some notes were added.

---

(1) This answer is a modification of [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29376856/1259917) for a different question.

Comment: thank a lot ! it's work fine, and sorry if i did not put the output i wanted. One more question!  concerning external variable. how can i receive it in the script? I have to receive a variable from a over shell script, the variable suppose (v) equal moto, car or plane. So, for exemple if i receive v="plane", how can i put it in a tag name <locomotion>plane</locomotion> for all of my clients (C,D)

Comment: i forgot to tell you the variable is coming from a shell script

Comment: Awk has a `-v` flag to accept external variables.  Using it like `-v -v=plane` you could pass a variable `v` into the script.  Internally, then you could hard-code adding the "locomotion" tags or use another `-v` flag.  Instead, I'd suggest a separate `defaults` file specified like `CD locomotion plane`, and in that case, move the construction of `dflt_flds` to a `FNR==NR` block to read in the `defaults` fields and now, default values.  Those default values could then be passed along to `c_flds` etc and then an altered `createObject()` could either print values from `data` or `defaults`.

Comment: sorry i'm back with an over one can you help me please on that one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29520440/awk-convert-csv-to-xml-and-wellform