# awk convert csv to xml and wellform

Tags: xml, csv, awk

One more question, i need to change the loop

```
name;num_tel;num_fixe;id_client;num_comd;email;city;date_liv
gwenael;0998452223;1038431234;50C;12345;gwa@yahoo.fr;London;08/07/2015
marcel;0966442312;1038453211;31C;654321;marcel@yahoo.fr;Pairs;08/06/2015
judith;0954674487;1045227937;23D;78965;judith@yahoo.fr;Toulouse;11/05/2015
paul;0998452223;1038431234;35X;19945;paul@yahoo.fr;Bordeaux;01/04/2015
toto;0966442312;1038453211;31Z;994991;toto@yahoo.frNice;02/12/2015 
marie;0954674487;1045227937;23C;78944;marie@yahoo.fr;Lille;04/08/2015
jacque;0998452223;1038431234;77C;18845;jacque@yahoo.fr;Bruges;09/05/2015
trucmuche;0966442312;1038453211;31Z;666321;trucmuche@yahoo.fr;Berlin;10/04/2015 
tata;0954674487;1045227937;23D;77965;tata@yahoo.fr;New-york;08/07/2015
```

i have to modifiy the awk script in fact using a loop for does not permish to do
what i need. 
1) I need to change the loop for to  a if condition because in the action i will have to 
add  tag name in the script in order to frame tag name from the csv.

for example in the script i will have    which is not 
in the csv  to frame    which is 
 in the  csv to output in xml.

2) User can add  tags in the csv with the default tags name before it is generated.
for exemple let's consider that tags city and date_liv had been added by user 
so they took position after the default tags of the csv (column 7 and 8). 
So how is it possible to add them with a loop starting at column 7 to the end to the xml ?

3) is it possible to rename a tag ? for exemple num_comd by command.

```
 <rows>
 <C = id_client>
    <client> 
                <identity>              
                            <name>  

                                <M>
                                        <num> </num>
                                        <num_tel> </num_tel>
                                        <num_comd> </num_comd>
                                </M>                                    
                </identity>

            <locomotion>car</locomotion>
</client>
</C>
</rows>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'am sorry if i do not clearly explain where i want to go in fact if you execute my code you will see that (awk file on the csv file) the output looks like this xml
but not well form. What i want is a output look like this xml with  indentations
Tag name in the xml must be order this way  sincerly i don't know if it can be done.
Also i will declare a in awk, variable var_awk=locomotive. So when i lunch the command 
'awk -v locomotion="car" -f file_awk.awk file_csv.csv', i would like to transform this variable to 
<locomotion>car</locomotion> into the xml.

Comment: my questions i have 2 questions
first modify the awk script in order to have the xml  well form and indent like this one i put.
Second is about transforming the var_awk=locomotion in a tag name like this <locomotion>car</locomotion>.

Comment: If you test the code you will see the difference between the output xml and the xml i posted.
All the content of the csv is not use. I only need the C and D client and the script does not  handle indentation. it appears like this
<C>  
<name>gwenael</name>
<num_tel>0998452223</num_tel>
<num_comd>12345   </num_comd>
</C>
Or i want to have the xml like i posted

Comment: Your desired XML output is still not [well formed](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-well-formed). Indentation isn't the problem, markup like `<C: id_client_proxy>` is the problem.

Comment: @EdMorton - Sorry my comment was directed toward the OP and not your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by writing a script that does what I think I understand you want and then you can tell us what it needs to do differently/additionally:

```
$ cat tst.awk                             
BEGIN { FS=";"; print "<rows>\n" }

NR==1 { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) f[$i]=i; next }

{ tag = $(f["id_client"]); gsub(/[0-9]/,"",tag) }

tag == "C" { type="client"; flds="num_tel num_comd" }
tag == "D" { type="pro"; flds="id_client num_fixe" }

{
    split("name "flds,n,/ /)
    printf     "<%s: %s>\n", tag, $(f["id_client"])
    printf     "    <%s>\n", type
    print      "        <identity>"
    for (i=1;i in n;i++)
        printf "            <%s>%s</%s>\n", n[i], $(f[n[i]]), n[i]
    print      "        </identity>"
    printf     "        <locomotion>%s</locomotion>\n", locomotion
    printf     "    </%s>\n", type
    printf     "</%s>\n\n", tag
}

END { print "</rows>" }
```

.

```
$ awk -v locomotion='car' -f tst.awk file
<rows>

<C: 50C>
    <client>
        <identity>
            <name>gwenael</name>
            <num_tel>0998452223</num_tel>
            <num_comd>12345</num_comd>
        </identity>
        <locomotion>car</locomotion>
    </client>
</C>

<C: 31C>
    <client>
        <identity>
            <name>marcel</name>
            <num_tel>0966442312</num_tel>
            <num_comd>654321</num_comd>
        </identity>
        <locomotion>car</locomotion>
    </client>
</C>

<D: 23D>
    <pro>
        <identity>
            <name>judith</name>
            <id_client>23D</id_client>
            <num_fixe>1045227937</num_fixe>
        </identity>
        <locomotion>car</locomotion>
    </pro>
</D>

</rows>
```

Now - what else does it need to do?

Comment: nice !  the indentation is good! in the tag name <c: id_client> is it possible to replace with the value of id_client ? and for the second question about the external  variable.  Can you declare a varible in awk script call locomotion and when we lunch the awk  command like this : -v locomotion="car" -f test_awk.awk file_csv.csv; the variable will be initiliase with 'car' and will be transform in tag name <locomotion>car </locomotion>

Comment: Thank you! It's exactaly what i want to have, tomorrow i will test it at job and leave a message if i have a problem Thann you! Great i waste a complete day on this

Comment: yes it work fine! and i'am preparing a over question

Comment: I see you have updated your question to contain 3 new questions and unfortunately I do not understand any of them. You should open a new question with PRECISE input and output that precisely matches that input and clearly shows what you want for each of your 3 new questions, possibly showing the output evolving step by step with each question. Please, please please be PRECISE with your expected output - I'm sorry but what you currently have posted is an incomprehensible mess with no relationship to the input you have posted.

Comment: i open a new question and i really try to give maximum information, i hope  i have been really precise this time  has you ask  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550714/convert-csv-to-xml-with-condition-and-various-tag-name